# Add characters to a column if the row starts with a specific character, and do this for odd and even rows separately

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have multiple alignment format (MAF) files that look like this:

```
##maf version=1
a       score=-1274
s       Chr10                                            34972197            2927       +       190919061         AACCTTGGGG
s       Chr11                                            36777315            2442       +       244384623         AACCTTGGGG

a       score=-60687
s       Chr1                                             81897274           61972       +       159217232          CGTTTTCCCGG
s       Chr1                                             33997294           32248       +       200980605
```

I would like to modify the second column of these files for lines that start with "s", to have something like this:

```
##maf version=1
a       score=-1274
s       species1.Chr10                                            34972197            2927       +       190919061         AACCTTGGGG
s       species2.Chr11                                            36777315            2442       +       244384623         AACCTTGGGG

a       score=-60687
s       species1.Chr1                                             81897274           61972       +       159217232          CGTTTTCCCGG
s       species2.Chr1                                             33997294           32248       +       200980605          CGTTTTCCCGG
```

Using this idea https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154220/adding-a-character-to-every-other-text-line

I am trying things like this:

```
awk '$1 == "s" {print ((NR%2)? "species1.":"") $0}'
```

But I am still far to reach my objective. Do you know how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- distance between fields is to be maintained

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
!/^s/ { print; sfx=0 }                  # if line does not start with "^s" then print line and reset sfx variable
 /^s/ { n=split($0,a,FS,seps)           # if line starts with "^s" then split current line; key is to save each separator as a separate seps[] array entry
        a[2]="species" ++sfx "." a[2]   # add prefix to value in 2nd field
        for (i=1;i<=n;i++)              # loop through all field/separator pairs
            printf a[i] seps[i]         # print each field/separator
        print ""                        # terminate line
      }
' maf.dat
```

**NOTE:** requires `GNU awk` for 4th argument to `split()`

This generates:

```
##maf version=1
a       score=-1274
s       species1.Chr10                                            34972197            2927       +       190919061         AACCTTGGGG
s       species2.Chr11                                            36777315            2442       +       244384623         AACCTTGGGG

a       score=-60687
s       species1.Chr1                                             81897274           61972       +       159217232          CGTTTTCCCGG
s       species2.Chr1                                             33997294           32248       +       200980605          CGTTTTCCCGG
```

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -pe 'if (/^s/) { s/Chr/species$x.Chr/; $x++ } else { $x = 1 }' file.maf
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line and outputs each line after processing;
- If the line starts with `s`, it prefixes `Chr` with `species` and the current number stored in `$x`, incrementing it;
- Otherwise, it sets `$x` to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '!/^s/{c=0} /^s/{sub(/[ \t]+/,"&species"++c".")} 1' file
##maf version=1
a       score=-1274
s       species1.Chr10                                            34972197            2927       +       190919061         AACCTTGGGG
s       species2.Chr11                                            36777315            2442       +       244384623         AACCTTGGGG

a       score=-60687
s       species1.Chr1                                             81897274           61972       +       159217232          CGTTTTCCCGG
s       species2.Chr1                                             33997294           32248       +       200980605
```

Answer (score 0):

sans the `match()`, `split()`, `arrays`, and vendor-proprietary solutions, all while maintaining original field gaps widths and contents (e.g. combo of spaces `(" ")` and horizontal tabs `("\t")` :

> ```
> {m,g}awk '
> BEGIN {   _ = length(FS = "^" (OFS = "s")) 
>       } (NF = NF) <+_  || sub("Chr", "species"(_-NR%_)".&", $_)'
> ```

```
##maf version=1
a       score=-1274
s       species1.Chr10                                            34972197            2927       +       190919061         AACCTTGGGG
s       species2.Chr11                                            36777315            2442       +       244384623         AACCTTGGGG

a       score=-60687
s       species1.Chr1                                             81897274           61972       +       159217232          CGTTTTCCCGG
s       species2.Chr1                                             33997294           32248       +       200980605          CGTTTTCCCGG
```